# How to use browser in window application that work like firefox?

Tags: c#, geckofx

I try to use geckofx in C# window application for web browser in window application. It work well except my video didn't play. 
My web url is : http://203.150.210.31/live/2d1f1f243014429a830def05c187e3074835c806056107efcb4932e446b25b92

Is there any way to make my browser in window application work as well as in web browser?
Here is my code to use browser in window application

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
            GeckoPreferences.User["plugin.state.flash"] = true;

            GeckoPreferences.User["browser.xul.error_pages.enabled"] = true;
            GeckoPreferences.User["media.navigator.enabled"] = true;
            GeckoPreferences.User["media.navigator.permission.disabled"] = true;
            GeckoPreferences.User["browser.cache.disk.enable"] = true;
            GeckoPreferences.User["places.history.enabled"] = false;
            GeckoPreferences.Default["extensions.blocklist.enabled"] = false;
        }

        private void geckoWebBrowser1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://203.150.210.31/live/2d1f1f243014429a830def05c187e3074835c806056107efcb4932e446b25b92");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) It's based on chromium embedded framework. If binary size is matter for you, you can try to use standard [WebBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.8) control based on IE. Or [WebViewCompatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webviewcompatible) from community toolkit, it's using Edge on Windows 10 and IE on other Windows versions